# TypeError when fitting Statsmodels OLS with standard errors clustered 2 ways

Tags: python, linear-regression, statsmodels, panel-data

### Context

Building on top of [How to run Panel OLS regressions with 3+ fixed-effect and errors clustering?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74140247/5433628) and notably [Josef's third comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74140247/how-to-run-panel-ols-regressions-with-3-fixed-effect-and-errors-clustering?noredirect=1#comment130905681_74140247), I am trying to adapt the *OLS Coefficients and Standard Errors Clustered by Firm and Year* section of [this example notebook](https://github.com/vgreg/python-se/blob/master/Standard%20errors%20in%20Python.ipynb) below:

```py
cluster_2ways_ols = sm.ols(formula='y ~ x', data=df).fit(cov_type='cluster',
                                                         cov_kwds={'groups': np.array(df[['firmid', 'year']])},
                                                         use_t=True)
```

to my own example dataset.

Note that I am able to reproduce this example (and it works). I can also add fixed-effects, by using `'y ~ x + C(firmid) + C(year)'` as formula instead.

### Problem

However, trying to port the same command to my example dataset (see code below), I'm getting the following error:

```
>>> model = sm.OLS.from_formula("gdp ~ population + C(year_publication) + C(country)", df)
>>> result = model.fit(
    cov_type='cluster',
    cov_kwds={'groups': np.array(df[['country', 'year_publication']])},
    use_t=True
)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/path/venv/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/statsmodels/regression/linear_model.py", line 343, in fit
    lfit = OLSResults(
  File "/path/venv/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/statsmodels/regression/linear_model.py", line 1607, in __init__
    self.get_robustcov_results(cov_type=cov_type, use_self=True,
  File "/path/venv/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/statsmodels/regression/linear_model.py", line 2568, in get_robustcov_results
    res.cov_params_default = sw.cov_cluster_2groups(
  File "/path/venv/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/statsmodels/stats/sandwich_covariance.py", line 591, in cov_cluster_2groups
    combine_indices(group)[0],
  File "/path/venv/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/statsmodels/tools/grouputils.py", line 55, in combine_indices
    groups_ = groups.view([('', groups.dtype)] * groups.shape[1])
  File "/path/venv/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/_internal.py", line 549, in _view_is_safe
    raise TypeError("Cannot change data-type for object array.")
TypeError: Cannot change data-type for object array.
```

I have tried to manually cast the `year_publication` to string/object using `np.array(df[['country', 'year_publication']].astype("str"))`, but it doesn't solve the issue.

### Questions

1. What is the cause of the `TypeError()`?
2. How to adapt the example command to my dataset?

---

### Minimal Working Example

```py
from io import StringIO

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm


DATA = """
"continent","country","source","year_publication","year_data","population","gdp"
"Africa","Angola","OECD",2020,2018,972,52.69
"Africa","Angola","OECD",2020,2019,986,802.7
"Africa","Angola","OECD",2020,2020,641,568.74
"Africa","Angola","OECD",2021,2018,438,168.83
"Africa","Angola","OECD",2021,2019,958,310.57
"Africa","Angola","OECD",2021,2020,270,144.02
"Africa","Angola","OECD",2022,2018,528,359.71
"Africa","Angola","OECD",2022,2019,974,582.98
"Africa","Angola","OECD",2022,2020,835,820.49
"Africa","Angola","IMF",2020,2018,168,148.85
"Africa","Angola","IMF",2020,2019,460,236.21
"Africa","Angola","IMF",2020,2020,360,297.15
"Africa","Angola","IMF",2021,2018,381,249.13
"Africa","Angola","IMF",2021,2019,648,128.05
"Africa","Angola","IMF",2021,2020,206,179.05
"Africa","Angola","IMF",2022,2018,282,150.29
"Africa","Angola","IMF",2022,2019,125,23.42
"Africa","Angola","IMF",2022,2020,410,247.35
"Africa","Angola","WorldBank",2020,2018,553,182.06
"Africa","Angola","WorldBank",2020,2019,847,698.87
"Africa","Angola","WorldBank",2020,2020,844,126.61
"Africa","Angola","WorldBank",2021,2018,307,239.76
"Africa","Angola","WorldBank",2021,2019,659,510.73
"Africa","Angola","WorldBank",2021,2020,548,331.89
"Africa","Angola","WorldBank",2022,2018,448,122.76
"Africa","Angola","WorldBank",2022,2019,768,761.41
"Africa","Angola","WorldBank",2022,2020,324,163.57
"Africa","Benin","OECD",2020,2018,513,196.9
"Africa","Benin","OECD",2020,2019,590,83.7
"Africa","Benin","OECD",2020,2020,791,511.09
"Africa","Benin","OECD",2021,2018,799,474.43
"Africa","Benin","OECD",2021,2019,455,234.21
"Africa","Benin","OECD",2021,2020,549,238.83
"Africa","Benin","OECD",2022,2018,235,229.33
"Africa","Benin","OECD",2022,2019,347,46.51
"Africa","Benin","OECD",2022,2020,532,392.13
"Africa","Benin","IMF",2020,2018,138,137.05
"Africa","Benin","IMF",2020,2019,978,239.82
"Africa","Benin","IMF",2020,2020,821,33.41
"Africa","Benin","IMF",2021,2018,453,291.93
"Africa","Benin","IMF",2021,2019,526,381.88
"Africa","Benin","IMF",2021,2020,467,313.57
"Africa","Benin","IMF",2022,2018,948,555.23
"Africa","Benin","IMF",2022,2019,323,289.91
"Africa","Benin","IMF",2022,2020,421,62.35
"Africa","Benin","WorldBank",2020,2018,983,271.69
"Africa","Benin","WorldBank",2020,2019,138,23.55
"Africa","Benin","WorldBank",2020,2020,636,623.65
"Africa","Benin","WorldBank",2021,2018,653,534.99
"Africa","Benin","WorldBank",2021,2019,564,368.8
"Africa","Benin","WorldBank",2021,2020,741,312.02
"Africa","Benin","WorldBank",2022,2018,328,292.11
"Africa","Benin","WorldBank",2022,2019,653,429.21
"Africa","Benin","WorldBank",2022,2020,951,242.73
"Africa","Chad","OECD",2020,2018,176,95.06
"Africa","Chad","OECD",2020,2019,783,425.34
"Africa","Chad","OECD",2020,2020,885,461.6
"Africa","Chad","OECD",2021,2018,673,15.87
"Africa","Chad","OECD",2021,2019,131,74.46
"Africa","Chad","OECD",2021,2020,430,61.58
"Africa","Chad","OECD",2022,2018,593,211.34
"Africa","Chad","OECD",2022,2019,647,550.37
"Africa","Chad","OECD",2022,2020,154,105.65
"Africa","Chad","IMF",2020,2018,160,32.41
"Africa","Chad","IMF",2020,2019,654,27.84
"Africa","Chad","IMF",2020,2020,616,468.92
"Africa","Chad","IMF",2021,2018,996,22.4
"Africa","Chad","IMF",2021,2019,126,93.18
"Africa","Chad","IMF",2021,2020,879,547.87
"Africa","Chad","IMF",2022,2018,663,520
"Africa","Chad","IMF",2022,2019,681,544.76
"Africa","Chad","IMF",2022,2020,101,55.6
"Africa","Chad","WorldBank",2020,2018,786,757.22
"Africa","Chad","WorldBank",2020,2019,599,593.69
"Africa","Chad","WorldBank",2020,2020,641,529.84
"Africa","Chad","WorldBank",2021,2018,343,287.89
"Africa","Chad","WorldBank",2021,2019,438,340.83
"Africa","Chad","WorldBank",2021,2020,762,594.67
"Africa","Chad","WorldBank",2022,2018,430,128.69
"Africa","Chad","WorldBank",2022,2019,260,242.59
"Africa","Chad","WorldBank",2022,2020,607,216.1
"Europe","Denmark","OECD",2020,2018,114,86.75
"Europe","Denmark","OECD",2020,2019,937,373.29
"Europe","Denmark","OECD",2020,2020,866,392.93
"Europe","Denmark","OECD",2021,2018,296,41.04
"Europe","Denmark","OECD",2021,2019,402,32.67
"Europe","Denmark","OECD",2021,2020,306,7.88
"Europe","Denmark","OECD",2022,2018,540,379.51
"Europe","Denmark","OECD",2022,2019,108,26.72
"Europe","Denmark","OECD",2022,2020,752,307.2
"Europe","Denmark","IMF",2020,2018,157,24.24
"Europe","Denmark","IMF",2020,2019,303,79.04
"Europe","Denmark","IMF",2020,2020,286,122.36
"Europe","Denmark","IMF",2021,2018,569,69.32
"Europe","Denmark","IMF",2021,2019,808,642.67
"Europe","Denmark","IMF",2021,2020,157,5.58
"Europe","Denmark","IMF",2022,2018,147,112.21
"Europe","Denmark","IMF",2022,2019,414,311.16
"Europe","Denmark","IMF",2022,2020,774,230.46
"Europe","Denmark","WorldBank",2020,2018,695,350.03
"Europe","Denmark","WorldBank",2020,2019,511,209.84
"Europe","Denmark","WorldBank",2020,2020,181,29.27
"Europe","Denmark","WorldBank",2021,2018,503,176.89
"Europe","Denmark","WorldBank",2021,2019,710,609.02
"Europe","Denmark","WorldBank",2021,2020,264,165.78
"Europe","Denmark","WorldBank",2022,2018,670,638.99
"Europe","Denmark","WorldBank",2022,2019,651,354.6
"Europe","Denmark","WorldBank",2022,2020,632,623.94
"Europe","Estonia","OECD",2020,2018,838,263.67
"Europe","Estonia","OECD",2020,2019,638,533.95
"Europe","Estonia","OECD",2020,2020,898,638.73
"Europe","Estonia","OECD",2021,2018,262,98.16
"Europe","Estonia","OECD",2021,2019,569,552.54
"Europe","Estonia","OECD",2021,2020,868,252.48
"Europe","Estonia","OECD",2022,2018,927,264.65
"Europe","Estonia","OECD",2022,2019,205,150.6
"Europe","Estonia","OECD",2022,2020,828,752.61
"Europe","Estonia","IMF",2020,2018,841,176.31
"Europe","Estonia","IMF",2020,2019,614,230.55
"Europe","Estonia","IMF",2020,2020,500,41.19
"Europe","Estonia","IMF",2021,2018,510,169.68
"Europe","Estonia","IMF",2021,2019,765,401.85
"Europe","Estonia","IMF",2021,2020,751,319.6
"Europe","Estonia","IMF",2022,2018,314,58.81
"Europe","Estonia","IMF",2022,2019,155,2.24
"Europe","Estonia","IMF",2022,2020,734,187.6
"Europe","Estonia","WorldBank",2020,2018,332,160.17
"Europe","Estonia","WorldBank",2020,2019,466,385.33
"Europe","Estonia","WorldBank",2020,2020,487,435.06
"Europe","Estonia","WorldBank",2021,2018,461,249.19
"Europe","Estonia","WorldBank",2021,2019,932,763.38
"Europe","Estonia","WorldBank",2021,2020,650,463.91
"Europe","Estonia","WorldBank",2022,2018,570,549.97
"Europe","Estonia","WorldBank",2022,2019,909,80.48
"Europe","Estonia","WorldBank",2022,2020,523,242.22
"Europe","Finland","OECD",2020,2018,565,561.64
"Europe","Finland","OECD",2020,2019,646,161.62
"Europe","Finland","OECD",2020,2020,194,133.69
"Europe","Finland","OECD",2021,2018,529,39.76
"Europe","Finland","OECD",2021,2019,800,680.12
"Europe","Finland","OECD",2021,2020,418,399.19
"Europe","Finland","OECD",2022,2018,591,253.12
"Europe","Finland","OECD",2022,2019,457,272.58
"Europe","Finland","OECD",2022,2020,157,105.1
"Europe","Finland","IMF",2020,2018,860,445.03
"Europe","Finland","IMF",2020,2019,108,47.72
"Europe","Finland","IMF",2020,2020,523,500.58
"Europe","Finland","IMF",2021,2018,560,81.47
"Europe","Finland","IMF",2021,2019,830,664.64
"Europe","Finland","IMF",2021,2020,903,762.62
"Europe","Finland","IMF",2022,2018,179,167.73
"Europe","Finland","IMF",2022,2019,137,98.98
"Europe","Finland","IMF",2022,2020,666,524.86
"Europe","Finland","WorldBank",2020,2018,319,146.01
"Europe","Finland","WorldBank",2020,2019,401,219.56
"Europe","Finland","WorldBank",2020,2020,711,45.35
"Europe","Finland","WorldBank",2021,2018,828,20.97
"Europe","Finland","WorldBank",2021,2019,180,66.3
"Europe","Finland","WorldBank",2021,2020,682,92.57
"Europe","Finland","WorldBank",2022,2018,254,81.2
"Europe","Finland","WorldBank",2022,2019,619,159.08
"Europe","Finland","WorldBank",2022,2020,191,184.4
"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(DATA))


model = sm.OLS.from_formula("gdp ~ population + C(year_publication) + C(country)", df)
result = model.fit(
    cov_type='cluster',
    cov_kwds={'groups': np.array(df[['country', 'year_publication']])},
    use_t=True
)
print(result.summary())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have realized that the `groups` must be an array of *integers* rather than of *objects*/strings.

Thus, **label encoding the string column** as follows:

```py
df["country"] = df["country"].astype("category")
df["country_id"] = df.country.cat.codes
```

and **using `country_id` to cluster the standard errors** solves the issue:

```py
result = model.fit(
    cov_type='cluster',
    cov_kwds={'groups': np.array(df[['country_id', 'year_publication']])},
    use_t=True
)
```

---

Fully working example:

```py
from io import StringIO

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm


DATA = """
"continent","country","source","year_publication","year_data","population","gdp"
"Africa","Angola","OECD",2020,2018,972,52.69
"Africa","Angola","OECD",2020,2019,986,802.7
"Africa","Angola","OECD",2020,2020,641,568.74
"Africa","Angola","OECD",2021,2018,438,168.83
"Africa","Angola","OECD",2021,2019,958,310.57
"Africa","Angola","OECD",2021,2020,270,144.02
"Africa","Angola","OECD",2022,2018,528,359.71
"Africa","Angola","OECD",2022,2019,974,582.98
"Africa","Angola","OECD",2022,2020,835,820.49
"Africa","Angola","IMF",2020,2018,168,148.85
"Africa","Angola","IMF",2020,2019,460,236.21
"Africa","Angola","IMF",2020,2020,360,297.15
"Africa","Angola","IMF",2021,2018,381,249.13
"Africa","Angola","IMF",2021,2019,648,128.05
"Africa","Angola","IMF",2021,2020,206,179.05
"Africa","Angola","IMF",2022,2018,282,150.29
"Africa","Angola","IMF",2022,2019,125,23.42
"Africa","Angola","IMF",2022,2020,410,247.35
"Africa","Angola","WorldBank",2020,2018,553,182.06
"Africa","Angola","WorldBank",2020,2019,847,698.87
"Africa","Angola","WorldBank",2020,2020,844,126.61
"Africa","Angola","WorldBank",2021,2018,307,239.76
"Africa","Angola","WorldBank",2021,2019,659,510.73
"Africa","Angola","WorldBank",2021,2020,548,331.89
"Africa","Angola","WorldBank",2022,2018,448,122.76
"Africa","Angola","WorldBank",2022,2019,768,761.41
"Africa","Angola","WorldBank",2022,2020,324,163.57
"Africa","Benin","OECD",2020,2018,513,196.9
"Africa","Benin","OECD",2020,2019,590,83.7
"Africa","Benin","OECD",2020,2020,791,511.09
"Africa","Benin","OECD",2021,2018,799,474.43
"Africa","Benin","OECD",2021,2019,455,234.21
"Africa","Benin","OECD",2021,2020,549,238.83
"Africa","Benin","OECD",2022,2018,235,229.33
"Africa","Benin","OECD",2022,2019,347,46.51
"Africa","Benin","OECD",2022,2020,532,392.13
"Africa","Benin","IMF",2020,2018,138,137.05
"Africa","Benin","IMF",2020,2019,978,239.82
"Africa","Benin","IMF",2020,2020,821,33.41
"Africa","Benin","IMF",2021,2018,453,291.93
"Africa","Benin","IMF",2021,2019,526,381.88
"Africa","Benin","IMF",2021,2020,467,313.57
"Africa","Benin","IMF",2022,2018,948,555.23
"Africa","Benin","IMF",2022,2019,323,289.91
"Africa","Benin","IMF",2022,2020,421,62.35
"Africa","Benin","WorldBank",2020,2018,983,271.69
"Africa","Benin","WorldBank",2020,2019,138,23.55
"Africa","Benin","WorldBank",2020,2020,636,623.65
"Africa","Benin","WorldBank",2021,2018,653,534.99
"Africa","Benin","WorldBank",2021,2019,564,368.8
"Africa","Benin","WorldBank",2021,2020,741,312.02
"Africa","Benin","WorldBank",2022,2018,328,292.11
"Africa","Benin","WorldBank",2022,2019,653,429.21
"Africa","Benin","WorldBank",2022,2020,951,242.73
"Africa","Chad","OECD",2020,2018,176,95.06
"Africa","Chad","OECD",2020,2019,783,425.34
"Africa","Chad","OECD",2020,2020,885,461.6
"Africa","Chad","OECD",2021,2018,673,15.87
"Africa","Chad","OECD",2021,2019,131,74.46
"Africa","Chad","OECD",2021,2020,430,61.58
"Africa","Chad","OECD",2022,2018,593,211.34
"Africa","Chad","OECD",2022,2019,647,550.37
"Africa","Chad","OECD",2022,2020,154,105.65
"Africa","Chad","IMF",2020,2018,160,32.41
"Africa","Chad","IMF",2020,2019,654,27.84
"Africa","Chad","IMF",2020,2020,616,468.92
"Africa","Chad","IMF",2021,2018,996,22.4
"Africa","Chad","IMF",2021,2019,126,93.18
"Africa","Chad","IMF",2021,2020,879,547.87
"Africa","Chad","IMF",2022,2018,663,520
"Africa","Chad","IMF",2022,2019,681,544.76
"Africa","Chad","IMF",2022,2020,101,55.6
"Africa","Chad","WorldBank",2020,2018,786,757.22
"Africa","Chad","WorldBank",2020,2019,599,593.69
"Africa","Chad","WorldBank",2020,2020,641,529.84
"Africa","Chad","WorldBank",2021,2018,343,287.89
"Africa","Chad","WorldBank",2021,2019,438,340.83
"Africa","Chad","WorldBank",2021,2020,762,594.67
"Africa","Chad","WorldBank",2022,2018,430,128.69
"Africa","Chad","WorldBank",2022,2019,260,242.59
"Africa","Chad","WorldBank",2022,2020,607,216.1
"Europe","Denmark","OECD",2020,2018,114,86.75
"Europe","Denmark","OECD",2020,2019,937,373.29
"Europe","Denmark","OECD",2020,2020,866,392.93
"Europe","Denmark","OECD",2021,2018,296,41.04
"Europe","Denmark","OECD",2021,2019,402,32.67
"Europe","Denmark","OECD",2021,2020,306,7.88
"Europe","Denmark","OECD",2022,2018,540,379.51
"Europe","Denmark","OECD",2022,2019,108,26.72
"Europe","Denmark","OECD",2022,2020,752,307.2
"Europe","Denmark","IMF",2020,2018,157,24.24
"Europe","Denmark","IMF",2020,2019,303,79.04
"Europe","Denmark","IMF",2020,2020,286,122.36
"Europe","Denmark","IMF",2021,2018,569,69.32
"Europe","Denmark","IMF",2021,2019,808,642.67
"Europe","Denmark","IMF",2021,2020,157,5.58
"Europe","Denmark","IMF",2022,2018,147,112.21
"Europe","Denmark","IMF",2022,2019,414,311.16
"Europe","Denmark","IMF",2022,2020,774,230.46
"Europe","Denmark","WorldBank",2020,2018,695,350.03
"Europe","Denmark","WorldBank",2020,2019,511,209.84
"Europe","Denmark","WorldBank",2020,2020,181,29.27
"Europe","Denmark","WorldBank",2021,2018,503,176.89
"Europe","Denmark","WorldBank",2021,2019,710,609.02
"Europe","Denmark","WorldBank",2021,2020,264,165.78
"Europe","Denmark","WorldBank",2022,2018,670,638.99
"Europe","Denmark","WorldBank",2022,2019,651,354.6
"Europe","Denmark","WorldBank",2022,2020,632,623.94
"Europe","Estonia","OECD",2020,2018,838,263.67
"Europe","Estonia","OECD",2020,2019,638,533.95
"Europe","Estonia","OECD",2020,2020,898,638.73
"Europe","Estonia","OECD",2021,2018,262,98.16
"Europe","Estonia","OECD",2021,2019,569,552.54
"Europe","Estonia","OECD",2021,2020,868,252.48
"Europe","Estonia","OECD",2022,2018,927,264.65
"Europe","Estonia","OECD",2022,2019,205,150.6
"Europe","Estonia","OECD",2022,2020,828,752.61
"Europe","Estonia","IMF",2020,2018,841,176.31
"Europe","Estonia","IMF",2020,2019,614,230.55
"Europe","Estonia","IMF",2020,2020,500,41.19
"Europe","Estonia","IMF",2021,2018,510,169.68
"Europe","Estonia","IMF",2021,2019,765,401.85
"Europe","Estonia","IMF",2021,2020,751,319.6
"Europe","Estonia","IMF",2022,2018,314,58.81
"Europe","Estonia","IMF",2022,2019,155,2.24
"Europe","Estonia","IMF",2022,2020,734,187.6
"Europe","Estonia","WorldBank",2020,2018,332,160.17
"Europe","Estonia","WorldBank",2020,2019,466,385.33
"Europe","Estonia","WorldBank",2020,2020,487,435.06
"Europe","Estonia","WorldBank",2021,2018,461,249.19
"Europe","Estonia","WorldBank",2021,2019,932,763.38
"Europe","Estonia","WorldBank",2021,2020,650,463.91
"Europe","Estonia","WorldBank",2022,2018,570,549.97
"Europe","Estonia","WorldBank",2022,2019,909,80.48
"Europe","Estonia","WorldBank",2022,2020,523,242.22
"Europe","Finland","OECD",2020,2018,565,561.64
"Europe","Finland","OECD",2020,2019,646,161.62
"Europe","Finland","OECD",2020,2020,194,133.69
"Europe","Finland","OECD",2021,2018,529,39.76
"Europe","Finland","OECD",2021,2019,800,680.12
"Europe","Finland","OECD",2021,2020,418,399.19
"Europe","Finland","OECD",2022,2018,591,253.12
"Europe","Finland","OECD",2022,2019,457,272.58
"Europe","Finland","OECD",2022,2020,157,105.1
"Europe","Finland","IMF",2020,2018,860,445.03
"Europe","Finland","IMF",2020,2019,108,47.72
"Europe","Finland","IMF",2020,2020,523,500.58
"Europe","Finland","IMF",2021,2018,560,81.47
"Europe","Finland","IMF",2021,2019,830,664.64
"Europe","Finland","IMF",2021,2020,903,762.62
"Europe","Finland","IMF",2022,2018,179,167.73
"Europe","Finland","IMF",2022,2019,137,98.98
"Europe","Finland","IMF",2022,2020,666,524.86
"Europe","Finland","WorldBank",2020,2018,319,146.01
"Europe","Finland","WorldBank",2020,2019,401,219.56
"Europe","Finland","WorldBank",2020,2020,711,45.35
"Europe","Finland","WorldBank",2021,2018,828,20.97
"Europe","Finland","WorldBank",2021,2019,180,66.3
"Europe","Finland","WorldBank",2021,2020,682,92.57
"Europe","Finland","WorldBank",2022,2018,254,81.2
"Europe","Finland","WorldBank",2022,2019,619,159.08
"Europe","Finland","WorldBank",2022,2020,191,184.4
"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(DATA))

df["country"] = df["country"].astype("category")
df["country_id"] = df.country.cat.codes

model = sm.OLS.from_formula("gdp ~ population + C(year_publication) + C(country)", df)
result = model.fit(
    cov_type='cluster',
    cov_kwds={'groups': np.array(df[['country_id', 'year_publication']])},
    use_t=True
)
print(result.summary())
```